# Django pass object to include

Tags: django, django-templates

I cannot do the following in Django:

```
{% include "admin/includes/pager.html" with title_pager="{{myobject.title}}" %}
```

or

```
{% include "admin/includes/pager.html" with title_pager="{{myobject}}" %}
```

What is the workaround?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You do not need to surround arguments in `{{ }}` brackets in template tags.

If it's a variable, not a string, then do not use `""` quotes.

The following should work:

```
{% include "admin/includes/pager.html" with title_pager=myobject.title %}

{% include "admin/includes/pager.html" with title_pager=myobject %}
```

See the Django docs for the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#include) for more information.

Comment: @Bwire The [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include) docs give an example with multiple variables. If you're still stuck after reading that, please open a new question.

Comment: [Updated link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) and answer: `{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}`

Comment: My template wasn't rendering, and I found that the reason was that I had it split over multiple lines, to make it more readable. But I needed `{%include "bla.html" with var=value %}` in a single line.

Comment: if the object is an array, can I do something equivalent to 

```{% include "admin/includes/pager.html" with title_pager=myobject[0] %}```

Comment: @plasma in Django templates you use dots rather than square brackets, e.g. `myobject.0`